# Haskell IO Monad and memory use

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm probably not understanding the IO monad very well.

If I write an application that is expected to run for many months, meanwhile logging its progress, will the IO monad hold all of the log information in RAM until the end?

From the blog on [IO Inside](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IO_inside), Haskell models the world as

```
main :: RealWorld -> ((), RealWorld)
```

so that IO does not occur during the execution of the Haskell part of the code, but only when the application returns from `main`.

I'm probably completely misinterpreting this. Could someone explain **when** Haskell actually does IO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> will the IO monad hold all of the log information in RAM until the end?

No. You shouldn't think of "the IO monad" as something that performs actions. It's just a mathematical way of representing imperative programs. The primitive imperative programs are things like `getChar`; `>>=` is used to glue two programs together into a larger imperative program. The IO monad is the set of all imperative programs.

Consider a program such as

```
main = putStr "Hello, " >> putStrLn "world!"
```

This means: `main` is a program that executes the program `putStr "Hello, "`, and when that is done, executes the program `putStrLn "world!"`. There's no need for the Haskell interpreter or the compiled program to keep any state in memory except for an instruction pointer, i.e. "where are we, and what do we execute next".

The `RealWorld -> ((), RealWorld)` metaphor may have confused you since it seems to imply a transformation of the outside world's state to a new state that has to be computed in its entirety, after which the world can be updated to reflect the computed state. That is not what happens at all. The Haskell wiki warns about this:

> The following story about IO is incorrect in that it cannot actually explain some important aspects of IO (including interaction and concurrency).

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I have read "Learn You a Haskell" (currently on my second reading of the monads section) and started "Real-World Haskell". Unless I missed something, neither makes it clear that IO occurs immediately, but rather, like other monads, is "accumulated" until the end. I guess I need to look at the assembly language output of the compiler to convince myself :-).

Comment: The `RealWorld -> ((), RealWorld)` metaphor certainly seems to imply that the transformation occurs in a pure form and is only emitted in its entirety at the end. I guess the underlying implementations of the IO operations actually occur "on demand".

Comment: @Ralph: The key to understanding the IO monad is that it accumulates *programs*, not actual input and output. Few Haskell tutorials explain this well.

Comment: `RealWorld -> ((), RealWorld)` considered in that way kind of fails to explain how `forever (putStrLn "hello!")` works (and the fact that it does should make it clear that IO isn't accumulated anywhere).

Comment: "the IO monad is the set of all imperative programs" - very interesting way of stating it.

Answer (score 4):

> will the IO monad hold all of the log information in RAM until the end?

No. Assuming you are using a sensible logging strategy.

Haskell performs IO when the result is demanded by your program; which for most actions is immediately. (The exception is lazy file input libraries, where files are not necessarily read until the data is used by the program).